# How to display 2 different array results in a single Angular view?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 arrays that I'm getting from an API, which has no FK or anything else in common.

In my ts the results are OK, however, the view is empty.

Debug results are shown as comments in the below code:

```
ngOnInit():void {
        this.data.loadShul()
            .subscribe(success => {
                if (success) { //Debug Results: success = true
                    this.cafe = this.data.cafe,//Debug Results: Array(1) 0:{cafe:Array(5),restaurant :Array(5)}
                        this.restaurant = this.data.restaurant;
                }
            });
    }`
```

My view:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let sy of cafe">
        name: {{sy.name}}  
    </li> 
</ul>
<ul style="background-color:red"> 
    <li *ngFor="let mk of restaurants">
        {{ mk.id }}
    </li>
</ul>
Im getting empty Li tag.
```

My json look like (EG Café):

```
`[
    {
               "cafe": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "TestCafe  ",
                "style": "dairy cafe"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "cafe test ",
                "style": "vegan"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "AnyCaffe  ",
                "style": "bakery"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Pastry    ",
                "style": "Breads and \u0086Pastry\u0087"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Fantastic ",
                "style": "pizza"
            }
        ],`
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the value of `this.cafe` and `this.restaurant` as an image or a console log output to the question. Need to see the full arrays.

Comment: console:(Eg café)[{…}]
0
:
cafe
:
Array(5)
0
:
id
:
1
name
:
"TestCafe  "
style
:
"dairy cafe"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
{id: 2, name: "cafe test ", style: "vegan"}
2
:
{id: 3, name: "AnyCaffe  ", style: "bakery"}
3
:
{id: 4, name: "Pastry    ", style: "Breads and Pastry"}
4
:
{id: 5, name: "Fantastic ", style: "pizza"}
length
:
5

Comment: Please add a clear json to the question not as a comment. And please format the json before puting it here

Comment: thanks. I have updated My Q.

Comment: I have upload an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine you need to change in html like this

```
  *ngFor="let sy of cafe[0]?.cafe
```

Hope this will show you `li` tags..

Comment: Have you checked response data in your subscriber method that what kind of data contains

Comment: Im not sure I understand your Q .

Comment: @Danny check this `this.data[0].cafe` as you posted json  data.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'cafe' of undefined - this.cafe = this.data[0].cafe,

Comment: I think you should check first this static binding `this.cafe = [
    {
               "cafe": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "TestCafe  ",
                "style": "dairy cafe"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "cafe test ",
                "style": "vegan"
            }  }][0]; ` if you get really this of array

Comment: @Danny now I upadating my post check this

Comment: (TS) Property 'cafe' does not exist on type 'Cafe'.- >    if (success) {
                    this.cafe = this.data.cafe[0].cafe;

Comment: Try in your html `*ngFor="let sy of cafe[0]?.cafe` like and see what happens?? And rest of code will be same as you posted.

Comment: This is working fine 





!. thanks, Please update your answer so I can mark it